# How to save and load google NLP reformer model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I´m working with the recent NLP model from [Google](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/01/reformer-efficient-transformer.html)

I have read a few post but mostly I´m plying over the colab [example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/trax/blob/master/trax/models/reformer/text_generation.ipynb#scrollTo=bQbQhqkK0cSH) Which have all the model ceations steps and testing function. The problem I have at now is that since the model takes a long time to train even using the google TPUs I need to save the the trained model, my guess is that it works similarly as the GPT-2 model in the sense that the model can be trainined over several sessions since it allows to stop training at any moment:

```
This will take at least 30 minutes to run to completion, but can safely
# be interrupted by selecting "Runtime > Interrupt Execution"
```

But i I have not found an example on how to save and load the model once trained. In case of GPT-2 a new directory was created automatically for each new model, and to use it it was necessary only point to that new directory, but for this one I´m not finding how to load a previously trained model.

EDIT:

In the notebook I saw this code:

```
# Set up a Trainer.
output_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/train_dir/')
!rm -f ~/train_dir/model.pkl  # Remove old model
trainer = trax.supervised.Trainer(
    model=trax.models.ReformerLM,
    loss_fn=trax.layers.CrossEntropyLoss,
    optimizer=trax.optimizers.Adam,
    lr_schedule=trax.lr.MultifactorSchedule,
    inputs=trax.supervised.inputs.Inputs(my_inputs),
    output_dir=output_dir,
    has_weights=True)
```

Which is deleteing the previous model, I looked into that directory I found this:

[image]

I used pickle to load this model.pkl file, which I also copied to my Gdrive folder:

```
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    reformer_model = pickle.load(handle)

reformer_model
```

But this is just a dictionary with the weigths, not a model to use directly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you remove the line "!rm -f ~/train_dir/model.pkl  # Remove old model" and change output_dir to point to the folder the saved model is in it will load that model and continue training from where you left off. If there is no model in that directory it will create a new one.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive',  force_remount=True)
%cd /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/


# Train tiny model with Trainer.
output_dir = "CornellMovieDialog/Model/"
trainer = trax.supervised.Trainer(
    model=tiny_transformer_lm,
    loss_fn=trax.layers.CrossEntropyLoss(),
    optimizer=trax.optimizers.Adafactor,  # Change optimizer params here.
    lr_schedule=trax.lr.MultifactorSchedule,  # Change lr schedule here.
    inputs=copy_inputs,
    output_dir=output_dir)
```